# Oracle SQL - how to split up a string into parts but not break up words

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, instr

I need to split a long description into 4 parts of up to 60 characters each, but I need each part to end with a space (not break up any words).  What is the best method to do this?  Below is the snippet of the code, however I need it to not break up words.

```
SELECT emplid as SHRQPNM_PIDM,
       substr(listagg(SSR_transcript_txt) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY text_seq_nbr), 1, 60),
       substr(listagg(SSR_transcript_txt) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY text_seq_nbr), 61, 60),
       substr(listagg(SSR_transcript_txt) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY text_seq_nbr), 121, 60),
       substr(listagg(SSR_transcript_txt) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY text_seq_nbr), 181, 60),
       to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') SHRQPNM_ACTIVITY_D,
FROM   PS_TSCRPT_TEXT
GROUP BY emplid, print_loc_SEQ) 
order by emplid, print_loc_SEQ;
```

example of current output:

```
DOCTORAL THESIS -A MEASUREMENT OF DISTORTION PRODUCT **OTOACOU|STIC** EMISSIONS WHILE ATTENDINGTO FAMILIAR AND UNFAMILIAR **VIS|UAL** STIMULATION|
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strip the trailing space from the output then you can use:

```sql
SELECT emplid as SHRQPNM_PIDM,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         listagg(SSR_transcript_txt) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY text_seq_nbr),
         '(.{1,60})( |$)',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS part1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         listagg(SSR_transcript_txt) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY text_seq_nbr),
         '(.{1,60})( |$)',
         1,
         2,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS part2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         listagg(SSR_transcript_txt) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY text_seq_nbr),
         '(.{1,60})( |$)',
         1,
         3,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS part3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         listagg(SSR_transcript_txt) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY text_seq_nbr),
         '(.{1,60})( |$)',
         1,
         4,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS part4,
       to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') SHRQPNM_ACTIVITY_D
FROM   PS_TSCRPT_TEXT
GROUP BY emplid, print_loc_SEQ
order by emplid, print_loc_SEQ;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ps_tscrpt_text (emplid, ssr_transcript_txt, text_seq_nbr, print_loc_seq) AS
SELECT 1,
       'DOCTORAL THESIS',
       1,
       1
FROM   DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,
       ' -A MEASUREMENT OF DISTORTION PRODUCT OTOACOUSTIC EMISSIONS WHILE ATTENDINGTO FAMILIAR AND UNFAMILIAR VISUAL STIMULATION|',
       2,
       1
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | SHRQPNM_PIDM | PART1 | PART2 | PART3 | PART4 | SHRQPNM_ACTIVITY_D |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | DOCTORAL THESIS -A MEASUREMENT OF DISTORTION PRODUCT | OTOACOUSTIC EMISSIONS WHILE ATTENDINGTO FAMILIAR AND | UNFAMILIAR VISUAL STIMULATION |  | *null* |

---

If you want to include the trailing space in the output (and have a maximum of 60 characters) then:

```sql
SELECT emplid as SHRQPNM_PIDM,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         listagg(SSR_transcript_txt) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY text_seq_nbr),
         '(.{1,59})( |$)',
         1,
         1
       ) AS part1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         listagg(SSR_transcript_txt) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY text_seq_nbr),
         '(.{1,59})( |$)',
         1,
         2
       ) AS part2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         listagg(SSR_transcript_txt) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY text_seq_nbr),
         '(.{1,59})( |$)',
         1,
         3
       ) AS part3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         listagg(SSR_transcript_txt) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY text_seq_nbr),
         '(.{1,59})( |$)',
         1,
         4
       ) AS part4,
       to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') SHRQPNM_ACTIVITY_D
FROM   PS_TSCRPT_TEXT
GROUP BY emplid, print_loc_SEQ
order by emplid, print_loc_SEQ;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e7a0054c0805ea4ea2f91b58b28a0f40)*